# MongoDB keeps returning Authentication Failed when using Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I was following an online tutorial to set up MongoDB with docker using MongoDB Compass.
This is what is inside my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: "mernstackdb"
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

I then run docker compose up -d and head over to MongoDB compass to set up a connection.

However, I keep running into such an error: [MongoDB compass shows authentication failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR2OO.png)

I have tried changing the username and password, else I am at a loss for what I should do, as this is my first time using MongoDB. I haven't found a solution online that uses MongoDB compass.
If it helps, I believe the first time I did this exact same steps a few months ago it worked. I have deleted the previous docker container, images and volumes.

Comment: Try setting the authSource in the connection string

Comment: Update connection string in compass and use `mongodb://localhost:27017/`